# Non Optimistic Locking in Redis

Tags: python, locking, redis

I have separate processes working on redis keys, one of them is very fast at updating, the second can take a bit to happen, but still needs to happen.

I'm looking to implement a real lock in redis, not just a watch that fails the following actions if the key is modified.

Is there a way to check for a watch on a key or something like that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Redis is single-threaded, so invoking any command on a key (or set of keys using MULTI) guarantees the operation to execute in isolation, effectively locking those keys during the operation.

Comment: Also, `WATCH` is supported in redis, read this: http://redis.io/topics/transactions#cas, if I were you I'd read the entire doc page on transactions.

Comment: So I need to get a value modify it and replace it in two processes. One process is doing this all the time and quickly. Another is not as often but takes a bit to modify the object, and I want to lock the key while this is happening so the set won't fail because the key has been modified while it is processing.

Comment: @Kevin  how did you solve this?

Comment: Solved by using 2 watches one that allowed access to the other.  Turns out its possible, but pretty ugly.  If possible its probably better to implement this locking outside of redis, in something like zookeeper